# C# Camera Object Tracking

Tags: c#, .net, camera, tracking

I would like to start with object tracking in C#.
Can you tell me where to start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a library called "Emgu", it's a wrapper for OpenCV and it is totally awesome for doing any kind of image/video processing. There are object tracking examples that should get you started.

http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

You can display your webcam feed in a window using just 7 lines of code:

```
using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.UI;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer(); //create an image viewer
Capture capture = new Capture(); //create a camera captue
Application.Idle += new EventHandler(delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  //run this until application closed (close button click on image viewer)
   viewer.Image = capture.QueryFrame(); //draw the image obtained from camera
});
viewer.ShowDialog(); //show the image viewer
```

There's also a forum where you can ask questions:
http://www.emgu.com/forum/

Comment: The forum link is dead. 

I did not find an explanation oh how to use of Object Tracking using Emgu. 
If you post the example that would be really helpful. Thanks!